# RPM created using checkinstall giving dependency error

Tags: linux, curl, rpm, openssl, checkinstall

Compiled openssl-1.0.1.i using commands:

```
export CFLAGS="-fPIC"
./config shared --openssldir=/usr/share/ssl
make depend
make all
make install
```

here it is not asking for any dependencies

I am able to run in terminal

```
bash-3.00# openssl
OpenSSl>
```

now I created RPM by running `checkinstall`; and trying to install this RPM on other setup.

I face this error:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
perl(WWW::Curl::Easy) is needed by openssl-1.0.1i-1.x86_64
```

When running:

```
rpm -qa | grep libcurl*
libcurl-devel-7.19.7-37.e16_4.x86_64
libuurl-7.19.7-37.e16_4.x86_64
```

curl is already installed

How to fix this error ??

Answer (score 1):

installing below RPM fixed this issue

```
rpm -ivh ../perl-WWW-Curl-4.09-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
```